# Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

I have two questions.

1. Is there any way to move data(CSV files in FTP server) periodically in to Azure Storage account using ADF?
2. After Switching Azure mode using

   switch-azuremode AzureResourceManager

I could not use Get- help datafactory

(Used Powershell in Admin mode, added Azure account using "Add-AzureAccount")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer your questions in order:

1. Not a native way at the moment, but you can create a [custom activity](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/) which loads your CSV files into Azure storage. The scheduling can be done via JSON (as most of the functionality in Data Factory). For the future you can expect that there will be some way in a future way.
2. Haven't tried it, but you could try `Get-Help azuredatafactory` (caution: no whitespaces) or `help azuredatafactory` or have a look at the [cmdlets reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn820234.aspx).